# Permutations without cycles

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools, circular-permutations

I want to generate all possible permutations of a list, where cyclic permutations (going from left to right) should only occur once.

Here is an example:

Let the list be `[A, B, C]`. Then I want to have permutations such as `[A, C, B]` but not `[B, C, A]` as this would be a circular permutation of the original list `[A, B, C]`. For the list above, the result should look like

```
[A, B, C]
[A, C, B]
[B, A, C]
[C, B, A]
```

Here is a minimal working example that uses `permutations()` from `itertools`.

```
from itertools import permutations


def permutations_without_cycles(seq: list):
    # Get a list of all permutations
    permutations_all = list(permutations(seq))

    print("\nAll permutations:")
    for i, p in enumerate(permutations_all):
        print(i, "\t", p)

    # Get a list of all cyclic permutations
    cyclic_permutations = [tuple(seq[i:] + seq[:i]) for i in range(len(seq))]

    print("\nAll cyclic permutations:")
    for i, p in enumerate(cyclic_permutations):
        print(i, "\t", p)

    # Remove all cyclic permutations except for one
    cyclic_permutations = cyclic_permutations[1:]  # keep one cycle
    permutations_cleaned = [p for p in permutations_all if p not in cyclic_permutations]

    print("\nCleaned permutations:")
    for i, item in enumerate(permutations_cleaned):
        print(i, "\t", item)


def main():
    seq = ["A", "B", "C"]
    permutations_without_cycles(seq=seq)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I would like to know if there is a method in `itertools` to solve this problem for efficiently?

Comment: In your example output, are `[A, C, B]`, `[B, A, C]` and `[C, B, A]` not "cycles"?

Comment: you may want to consider using `set`s. you can have all the values you dont want in a set and subtract them from you total permutatuins

Comment: @IainShelvington I may not have been precise enough. I want to exclude cyclic permutations in only one direction reading from left to right. I don't know how to describe it better.

Comment: @Gilfoyle how is `[B, C, A]` a circular permutation of `[A, B, C]` but `[C, B, A]` is not a circular permutation of `[A, C, B]`? Seems like they are both cyclical from left-to-right, unless you are only excluding cyclical permutations of the original list?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, I want to exclude only cyclical permutations of the original list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's unusual, so no, that's not already in itertools. But we can optimize your way significantly (mainly by filtering out the unwanted cyclics by using a *set* instead of a list, or even by just the single next unwanted one). Even more efficiently, we can compute the indexes of the unwanted permutations<sup>[*]</sup> and `islice` between them. See the full code at the bottom.

[*] Using a simplified version of [permutation_index](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.combination_index) from more-itertools.

Benchmark results, using `list(range(n))` as the sequence. Ints compare fairly quickly, so if the sequence elements were some objects with more expensive comparisons, my `efficient` solution would have an even bigger advantage, since it's the only one that doesn't rely on comparing permutations/elements.

```
8 elements:
  1.76 ±  0.07 ms  efficient
  3.60 ±  0.76 ms  optimized_iter
  4.65 ±  0.81 ms  optimized_takewhile
  4.97 ±  0.43 ms  optimized_set
  8.19 ±  0.31 ms  optimized_generator
 21.42 ±  1.19 ms  original

9 elements:
 13.11 ±  2.39 ms  efficient
 34.37 ±  2.83 ms  optimized_iter
 40.87 ±  4.49 ms  optimized_takewhile
 46.74 ±  2.27 ms  optimized_set
 78.79 ±  3.43 ms  optimized_generator
237.72 ±  5.76 ms  original

10 elements:
160.61 ±  4.58 ms  efficient
370.79 ± 14.71 ms  optimized_iter
492.95 ±  2.45 ms  optimized_takewhile
565.04 ±  9.68 ms  optimized_set
         too slow  optimized_generator
         too slow  original
```

Code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=1VfBbttGEL0L6D8s3INJe-VaTh3EAlQgDdAf6CkQCIGihvZW5JLZXUZRDX9JL7m09_5CPiNf05lZkVpKtOCiuVSALXJ35s3Mm9nZ0R9_1Vv3UOnPn_9sXD5-8_W7y9xUpVAOjKuqwgpV1pVxogZTNi51qtJWiuwhVVoKZQuVgRS5KlA-TwuLLy5dw-ZBFTBiJKdKUK6F8W9-xxKcdSrrjJSQIqp1K_joRbKqKCBjo63MCj40MBp9L95XjRGVUfdKp4UUvzXWiY3CYBo08wCiNko7-0NWlSXggxSpXgkDrjFa6XsWMWCbwo1WkHdAkYUPU1GgX_F0JPATBr5Ii0LMeDcK10kpjlk822bIySLcRY25a-oCSGyupom4FPQ0VUks8soIJZQWJtX3EBWgPVhyAm1gdT6ZJsfuZgUSCityoGZLNVk6ikjluKErR5sD2B7YMzeIPzpKBycCg_wIBl-qGtOufvdKnm2_AquFBRdSLk6E_fhSEidSdDw-hc4HdRoN2LhaLLJKOyxtu1hIMZBhCvSXxmDtmH0MwlU7ZLHc-jqk4rJYZQUIDZ-caPQm1Q5FA8wDIujEHRUfidSpcTbaLdAHT9Ps2Llue6ugWLHZSLlYdusnSNpj08euVY0WnmO7J-uNse_KIX9klrgjjEOX8NwHueAWckWnnENPl2hsF6rn-S1WJPG8SbffhuGuMf1faQ4CQF1mm7hG8_-N6ffgsDl-Y7bvQaMtVx0XNenYZ7kNeGVBv_oiVl_KKHdCxG6boe0nhtoh7c5mjNjfpM_SQLoeyA9pBTHwDcb4zPK7qqwbB8yl0iv4BFZUOb8O0Wn5vvI3rFiC2wBoEi6ZZ8hzlSm815iDE1V8muxBwmVfecHOIsSkW9d0Ce7477FqKm-ilyl9UPgt3nVv9SDDOAeg6ngSH9Pf6vvvC9S63Bu-EJESP3Xvg92KOfXByh3KOIy1r3RYisPk-O_LgKR9Tdh_cRrzRmeUr_1gM3CkZP8ClQfXiBxqenJfM1SO4_EYK9IYnK40WItuQbbGQsWU0rhw9vZMirOf6d-7s2REyckpOeze7hjTfBVd5FwFOANSP0pL7Ehxi_JKTuSP8lbeyRv5ehAjtRbnTD9QeaCYjl04jCEaaQYldberCW-EdXc1E--bxaGll1vz3PxaA93sYB2SQieLHklCetQ4JCEOnttzIcU5FMCj5_QcYUmCpl-eZPKpmCcHfj51h5gGYxvlQek7P0RidU_gFevxsGZxIIZVxLDzPInn09sk6ZTaoef8kebqyKHPr69u8ifx5W_xyEM2r93yGjaJ81HH3mLP9s1t4MdzzLKP1Hp5vI-KtFyu0qmf1aO2Qq7xTzflEsxs0j9KbQBXaV2DxoDiUT-Ru0DZqhRr2M6Yo7DPMfktcwflyLkLCuVNHLdpPNq7O7E3ue425zfTJPa_mXY_ndqfUP8A)):

```py
from itertools import permutations, chain, islice, filterfalse, takewhile
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
from collections import deque

# Your original, just without the prints/comments, and returning the result
def original(seq: list):
    permutations_all = list(permutations(seq))
    cyclic_permutations = [tuple(seq[i:] + seq[:i]) for i in range(len(seq))]
    cyclic_permutations = cyclic_permutations[1:]
    permutations_cleaned = [p for p in permutations_all if p not in cyclic_permutations]
    return permutations_cleaned


# Your original with several optimizations
def optimized_set(seq: list): 
    cyclic_permutations = {tuple(seq[i:] + seq[:i]) for i in range(1, len(seq))}
    return filterfalse(cyclic_permutations.__contains__, permutations(seq))


# Further optimized to filter by just the single next unwanted permutation
def optimized_iter(seq: list):
    def parts():
        it = permutations(seq)
        yield next(it),
        for i in range(1, len(seq)):
            skip = tuple(seq[i:] + seq[:i])
            yield iter(it.__next__, skip)
        yield it
    return chain.from_iterable(parts())


# Another way to filter by just the single next unwanted permutation
def optimized_takewhile(seq: list):
    def parts():
        it = permutations(seq)
        yield next(it),
        for i in range(1, len(seq)):
            skip = tuple(seq[i:] + seq[:i])
            yield takewhile(skip.__ne__, it)
        yield it
    return chain.from_iterable(parts())


# Yet another way to filter by just the single next unwanted permutation
def optimized_generator(seq: list):
    perms = permutations(seq)
    yield next(perms)
    for i in range(1, len(seq)):
        skip = tuple(seq[i:] + seq[:i])
        for perm in perms:
            if perm == skip:
                break
            yield perm
    yield from perms


# Compute the indexes of the unwanted permutations and islice between them
def efficient(seq):
    def parts():
        perms = permutations(seq)
        yield next(perms),
        perms_index = 1
        n = len(seq)
        for rotation in range(1, n):
            index = 0
            for i in range(n, 1, -1):
                index = index * i + rotation * (i > rotation)
            yield islice(perms, index - perms_index)
            next(perms)
            perms_index = index + 1
        yield perms
    return chain.from_iterable(parts())


funcs = original, optimized_generator, optimized_set, optimized_iter, optimized_takewhile, efficient


#--- Correctness checks

seq = ["A", "B", "C"]
for f in funcs:
    print(*f(seq), f.__name__)

seq = 3,1,4,5,9,2,6
for f in funcs:
    assert list(f(seq)) == original(seq)

for n in range(9):
    seq = list(range(n))
    for f in funcs:
        assert list(f(seq)) == original(seq)


#--- Speed tests

def test(seq, funcs):
    print()
    print(len(seq), 'elements:')

    times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
    def stats(f):
        ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
        return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):5.2f} ms '

    for _ in range(25):
        for f in funcs:
            t = timeit(lambda: deque(f(seq), 0), number=1)
            times[f].append(t)

    for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
        print(stats(f), f.__name__)

test(list(range(8)), funcs)
test(list(range(9)), funcs)
test(list(range(10)), funcs[2:])
```

Comment: May I know why this was voted not useful? The OP even accepted it...

Answer (score 0):

Claim: The set permutations of N elements that are not related to each other via cyclic permutation is in one-to-one correspondence with all permutations of N-1 elements.

Not rigorous proof: Any permutation {i1,i2,...,iN}, with the k'th element ik=1, can be transformed by cyclic permutations to the permutation {1,j2,...,jN} (with j2=i(k+1),j3=i(k+2),...). The permutation {1,j2,...,jN} uniquely represents an orbit of cyclic permutations. Hence, any permutation of N-1 elements {j2,...,jN} represents the orbit of permutation of N elements not related by cycles.

The easiest way to convince yourself is to count dimensions (number of elements):
Dim[All permutation of N] = N!
Dim[Cyclic permutations] = N
Dim[Permutation of N not related by cycles] = N!/N = (N-1)! = Dim[All permutation of N-1]

Then what you need to do:
0. Given list ["1","2",...,"N"]

1. Pop the first element ["2",...,"N"]
2. Compute all permutations ["2","3"...,"N"], ["3","2"...,"N"]...
3. Append "1" to each list ["1","2","3"...,"N"], ["1","3","2"...,"N"]...

Answer (score -2):

See this post: [Python: Generate All Permutations Subject to Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633156/python-generate-all-permutations-subject-to-condition)

The idea is to pull the first element from the list, generate all permutations of the **remaining** elements and append those permutations to that first element.

Comment: That would only produce the first two of their four desired permutations in their example.

Comment: The third permutation `[B, A, C]` is a cyclic rotation of the second permutation `[A, C, B]`; and the fourth is a also a cyclic rotation of the second.  So that part of the question seems ill-posed.

Comment: I now see the OP comment "I want to exclude only cyclical permutations of the original list".  It's a strange condition.

Comment: I agree it looks strange, but it is what they asked for. Twice in the question already (with the explicit output and with their working code) and then a third time in the comments, which were specifically about that and  whether that was a mistake or indeed desired.

Comment: I'd btw say the direct answer to their question (*"I would like to know if there is a method in itertools to solve this problem for efficiently?"*) is *"No, not even with minor extra code"*. The most efficient and simple idea I have is to use `more_itertools.permutation_index` to find the indexes of the undesired cyclic permutations and then repeatedly use `islice` to fetch all the desired permutations between them.

Comment: Hmm, well, or maybe the special nature of these particular undesired permutations make the index computations simpler. Plus looking at the `permutation_index` source code, that's already pretty simple.